# Hombrew's gem installs old version of a ruby gem

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, homebrew

I used Homebrew to install a newer version of ruby on macOS Big Sur. When I try to install docker-sync by using Homebrew's gem, it installs version 0.0.11. When I use macOS system default gem it installs version 0.5.14.

Homebrew installs gem to /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem:

```
$ /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem install docker-sync
Fetching docker-sync-0.0.11.gem
Successfully installed docker-sync-0.0.11
Parsing documentation for docker-sync-0.0.11
Installing ri documentation for docker-sync-0.0.11
Done installing documentation for docker-sync after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

macOS' default gem is placed at /usr/bin/gem:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/gem install docker-sync 
Fetching docker-sync-0.5.14.gem
Successfully installed docker-sync-0.5.14
Parsing documentation for docker-sync-0.5.14
Installing ri documentation for docker-sync-0.5.14
Done installing documentation for docker-sync after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

When I install docker-sync using Homebrew's gem and then call `gem update` I run into an error:

```
$ /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem update
Updating installed gems
Updating docker-sync
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `request' for nil:NilClass
```

If I search for docker-sync, homebrew's gem is listing the right version:

```
$ /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem search docker-sync

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

docker-sync (0.5.14)
rake-tasks-docker-sync (1.0.0)
```

The configuration of Homebrew's gem looks like this:

```
$ /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem env 
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.2.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.0.0 (2020-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin20]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/mylogin/.gem/ruby/3.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/mylogin/.local/share/gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-darwin-20
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
     - /Users/mylogin/.gem/ruby/3.0.0
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/TeX/texbin
```

The configuration of macOS' default gem looks like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/gem env                
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.3 (2019-04-16 patchlevel 62) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/mylogin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/mylogin/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-20
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
     - /Users/mylogin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/TeX/texbin
```

I run `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem sources -u` and `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem sources -c` but that did not resolve the problems.

Why doesn't homebrew's gem install the newest version of docker-sync? Why does homebrew's gem produce the error when I try to update the old version of docker-sync?

Comment: I'd recommend using something like [`rbenv`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) if you're doing anything serious in Ruby. This gives you access to much more up-to-date versions of Ruby.

Comment: I'll take a look on that. Thank you. Nevertheless I'd like to understand what's going wrong, as I cannot see any serious difference between the environment of hombrew's gem and macOS' default gem.

Comment: If you want to dig into this some more you'll need to look very closely at the stack trace you get, or if you don't get one, figure out how to.

Comment: Unfortunately, gem update does not print any stacktrace as you can see above. The error messages seems quite generic to me. I would appreciate any hint where and how to start looking deeper into the error.

Comment: I created an issue on github regarding that question: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/74176

Comment: This seems to be a ruby 2 versus ruby 3 issue and not an issue of Homebrew's gem vs. macOS default gem. See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/74176 and https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/issues/762 for details.

Comment: There's lots of minor, but irritating 2.x to 3.0 upgrade issues. If this is one of them it's not surprising, but glad you could pin it down.